# L'Hopitals rule $n(\sqrt{n^2+1} - n)$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt{n^2+1} - n)$$

I have no idea how to use Lhops on this. Literally no idea, and I can't find any google search on it at all. I know that if I differentiate it that is no help at all because I get the product rule for differentiation which spawns more indeterminate cases.

Comment: Multiply by the ratio of conjugate/conjugate, and only multiply out the top. In these problems this tric often turns it into something one can apply LHopital to.

Comment: To apply L'Hospital's rule you first need $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

Comment: By coincidence, I just did this problem yesterday. Use @kunnysan's advice

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is **not** about blindly differentiating the expressions involved when an indeterminate form appears, so you comment about "product rule" is nonsense.

Comment: L'Hospital rule is not supposed to used for limit of sequences, but rather for limit of functions which are in special indeterminate forms. Here one could use the L'Hospital by changing integer $n$ into real $x$ and transforming the function in one of the indeterminate forms, but doing so is an overkill and problem is very easily solved by using hint from Peter Tamaroff.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $$\left( {\sqrt {{n^2} + 1}  - n} \right)\frac{{\sqrt {{n^2} + 1}  + n}}{{\sqrt {{n^2} + 1}  + n}} = \frac{{{n^2} + 1 - {n^2}}}{{\sqrt {{n^2} + 1}  + n}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {{n^2} + 1}  + n}}$$

Note we used $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$

Answer (score 3):

To do it by L'hospital rule:

**Hint** : $$n(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)=\frac{\sqrt{1+{1\over n^2}}-1}{{1\over n^2}}$$

Comment: One **must** point out that L'Hôpital should be applied to functions and not to sequences.

Comment: What to you mean? A sequence is **not** a function?

Comment: *Fair enough:* functions of the form $f:A\subset \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that are differentiable.

Comment: I guess, both numerator and denominator are differentiable here as functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Of course, but there is a difference between a sequential limit and a functional limit. For example, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi n)=0$ yet $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sin(2\pi x)$ fails to exist. What I guess you're thinking is that if the functional limit exists, then so does the sequential limit.

Comment: Yes, That's right. And here, I considered the continuous function $f(x)=x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $n=\frac1h,$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt{n^2+1} - n)=\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+h^2}-1}{h^2}\text{ which is of the form  }\frac00$$

So, we can safely apply L'Hôpital's rule here.

Alternatively without using l'Hospital's rule, 
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{1+h^2}-1}{h^2}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h^2)-1}{h^2(\sqrt{1+h^2}+1)}\text{ (rationalizing the numerator)}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{1+h^2}+1}\text{ as }h\ne0 \text{ as }h\to0$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{1+0^2}+1}=\frac12$$